# Multithreaded unoconv (libreoffice)

Tags: multithreading, pdf, libreoffice, pdf-conversion, unoconv

I am trying to convert a few large .doc and .rtf files to PDF on linux. 
The command is:

`unoconv -f pdf largefile.doc`

My machine has 8 cores, however when i run htop, it shows that only 1 core is being used at 100%. And the conversion takes several minutes. I am wondering if there's a multithreaded/parallel version of the unoconv utility? Or libreoffice writer? Or perhaps another utility that can convert multiple file types into PDF.

Just to clarify, a single file takes a long time to convert, i'm not looking to convert several files in parallel.

UPDATE: one .doc file is taking 15 hours to convert. The file has about 30 pages and each page contains a screenshot. Perhaps I need another utility?